# 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation' SQL upgrade error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my SQL 2008 R2 standard edition to SQL 2012.
During the upgrade i get the following error

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..

The `eventType is 0x90F5BF4F%400xDC80C325` and `Message ID is 5000`

There is no additional information anywhere in the logs.